# 'authority' should be in Uri format Parameter name: authority

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I developed my mvc app based on this example:
https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet

Authentication works perfect with Azure AAD, and I can see the user is logged on:

http://screencast.com/t/v7G6OgXC

However in the following controller I want to print out some APP properties, and I get the error above

> 'authority' should be in Uri format Parameter name: authority
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: 'authority' should be in
>   Uri format Parameter name: authority

The code I have in the controller is like this:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace PruebasAD.Controllers
{
    public class ActiveDirectoryController : Controller
    {
        private static string azureAdGraphApiEndPoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AzureAdGraphApiEndPoint"];
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppKey"];

        // GET: ActiveDirectory
        public ActionResult GetAzureAadApp()
        {
            // Instantiate an instance of ActiveDirectoryClient.
            Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(azureAdGraphApiEndPoint);
            ActiveDirectoryClient adClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
                serviceRoot,
                async () => await GetAppTokenAsync());

            // Create the extension property
            string extPropertyName = "VehInfo";
            ExtensionProperty extensionProperty = new ExtensionProperty()
            {
                Name = extPropertyName,
                DataType = "String",
                TargetObjects = { "User" }
            };

            Application app =(Application)adClient.Applications.Where(
                    a => a.AppId == clientId).ExecuteSingleAsync().Result;

            if (app == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to get a reference to application in Azure AD.");
            }

            return View(app);
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetAppTokenAsync()
        {
            string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
            string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppKey"];
            string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
            string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
            string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
            string azureAdGraphApiEndPoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AzureAdGraphApiEndPoint"];
            // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
            string graphResourceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:GraphResourceId"];

            string Authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

            // Instantiate an AuthenticationContext for my directory (see authString above).
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance, false);

            // Create a ClientCredential that will be used for authentication.
            // This is where the Client ID and Key/Secret from the Azure Management Portal is used.
            ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

            // Acquire an access token from Azure AD to access the Azure AD Graph (the resource)
            // using the Client ID and Key/Secret as credentials.
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(azureAdGraphApiEndPoint, clientCred);

            // Return the access token.
            return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        }
    }


    public class CompanyInfo
    {
        public int Nit;
        public string Nombre;
    }
}
```

and the web.config with some things changed for security

```
<add key="ida:GraphResourceId" value="https://graph.windows.net" />
    <add key="ida:GraphUserUrl" value="https://graph.windows.net/{0}/me?api-version=2013-11-08" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="xx-b1aa-42ab-9693-6c22d01ca338" />
    <add key="ida:AppKey" value="xx/6Vsq0CuhQyYVcR5Vggw=" />
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="xx.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44300/" />
    <add key="ida:AzureAdGraphApiEndPoint" value="https://graph.windows.net/xx-d5f0-453b-8f60-2be9b41b2ea0" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass `Authority` to `AuthenticationContext()` instead of `aadInstance`:

```
// Instantiate an AuthenticationContext for my directory (see authString above).
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
```